# Solder new RAM in a 2015 Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory, repair

I know that the new rMBPs have no "user-serviceable" RAM. But is it possible to solder a new RAM chip onto a 2015 rMBP? Given that the technician doing this is able to install the new chip without damaging anything, would it work?

Comment: Probably be cheaper and less risky to sell the MBP used and buy the used one you want.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**The short answer is yes (anything is possible), but is it feasible?**

There's a ton of responses out there whether you can/cannot re-solder memory chips to Apple logic boards in an attempt to upgrade RAM.  Unfortunately, there is a lot of misinformation out there.  Basically, they all revolve around one of the following three themes:

- It's extremely difficult/impossible
- No idea how much memory can be addressed
- Physical space to "add more chips"

### Impossible and/or extremely difficult

[Replacing a chip](https://youtu.be/x0hGYf65RpA) is actually quite an easy process if you have a BGA rework station and a little bit of practice.<sup>1</sup> You actually don't need a significant amount of "electronic engineering" skill to remove a chip and replace it with another.   It doesn't need to go back to the factory as doing BGA rework doesn't damage the board.

Are you going to do this with a [soldering iron/gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering_iron) that you get from Radio Shack or your local electronics supply store?  No.

However, obtaining a BGA rework station is not out of the realm of possibility either.  A quick search on [Amazon](http://radnex.us/BGA_Rework_Station) yields both *infrared* and *hot air* rework stations that vary in price from $150 to $6,000 depending on the the bells and whistles you want.  The key here is how accurately the rework station can deliver the heat necessary to flow the solder.

[image: BGA Rework Station]

*Because the heated air or infrared light is focused directly to the work piece, heat damage to the remainder of the board is mitigated*

As for my personal experience, I have had GPU's replaced in Apple logic boards that **weren't** covered by Apple's GPU replacement program using this exact method and not only got a year's warranty on the work, but the logic boards lasted for years after.

**So, can this work be done?  *Yes.*  Quite easily.**

### How much memory can be addressed?

There has been a lot of speculation as to how much memory a computer can address.  There has even been conjecture on the "additional (physical) space" required for the new chips.

First and foremost, the memory limit is primarily determined by the CPU. For example, on an original [i7-920 CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI), the maximum amount of memory that can be addressed is 24GB of RAM.

[image: Memory Specs]

If you notice, Intel states that it's determined by the "type of memory."  This is where the logic board comes into play. Depending on the type, the logic board and the memory modules available at the time may impose a limit less than what the CPU can address.

Haven't you ever noticed that [everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) has tested higher configurations that what was technically specified by Apple?

[image: Max Ram]

This is because what was available at the time the product was released, higher density memory chips weren't generally available.  When they become available,  you can upgrade your Mac *past* the specified limit.

To see what your particular CPU can address, [obtain the CPU identifier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238789/119271) from your machine and get the specs from http://www.intel.com

### Space to add more...

In the *pre-soldered RAM days*, when you wanted to upgrade your Mac with more RAM, were you stopped because there wasn't any more "real estate" on your logic board?  No.  You *replaced* the module(s) with larger ones.

Memory modules (of a [particular family](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/memory-cards-modules/memory-modules/505?k=memory&k=&pkeyword=memory&v=557&pv149=40&FV=ffe001f9&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25))<sup>2</sup> only differ in density.  As for physical layout, pin out configuration, voltages, etc., they are identical.  So, using the example I linked with DigiKey, you could have 8 modules of 16M for 128M or 8 modules of 512M for 4G.  Same real estate, same configuration.

**So, can you get "bigger" memory chips?  *Yes*.**

### Is all of this feasible?

Again, in the *pre-soldered RAM days* of Apple it was quite easy to upgrade your memory.  Now, unless you are willing to invest in a rework machine and put in some practice reworking a BGA chip you are going to have to send this out to be done by someone with experience.

I have sent many clients damaged logic boards to a firm in NYC that specializes in this type of work.  It usually costs between $350 and $500 depending on the severity and what parts are needed. Estimating that replacement memory chips would be around $200 and the work would be on the high end given that there are multiple chips to replace (say $450), you are looking at $650 to upgrade your memory.

A quick look on [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MF839LL/A&step=config#) tells me that to upgrade a MacBook Pro from 8GB to 16GB is only $200.

[image: MBP Memory Prices]

### Bottom line:  Is this feasible?

Keep in mind, if you undertake this type of modification, you will void any warranty on your MacBook, if there is one still in effect.

So, we are left with a cost comparison:

- (Est) $650 to upgrade your memory & void your warranty
- $200 to get it from Apple and keep warranty in full effect.

### *No* this is not feasible.  Period.

---

<sup>1</sup> I actually did this work about 4 times a year, at the end of every fiscal quarter, when our company would go "all hands on deck" to the manufacturing and shipping departments to get as much product out the door as possible.  Normally, I worked in product management as a go between marketing and development.  However, for about a week every 3 months I was in the QA department re-flowing chips using a hot air rework station like the one referenced.  They gave me this job so the actual tech could spend time diagnosing the problem rather than spend time doing the mundane work of re-flowing a BGA.  I had about an hour or two of training and became quite proficient at it.

<sup>2</sup> The memory shown here is for illustration purposes only.  It's not intended to be the specification for memory used in any Apple or other manufacturers' product.

---

Comment: "The short answer is yes (anything is possible)" Nice for motivational posters but not true in reality. The other answer is far better because it questions and analyses whether the machine could address anything greater, which isn't a safe assumption in machines with soldered parts.

Comment: @underscore_d  I like succinct, but the other answer is technically incorrect.  See my update.

Comment: Very substantial edit, thanks. However, not that I have any stock in the other answer, but how is it technically incorrect? it arrived at the same conclusion as you, earlier ;-) or am I missing something? The only difference I can see is that it was speculating whether SPD reprogramming would be required, which you seem to indicate isn't.

Comment: Specifically the "space" required is false, the SPD, is conjecture, especially since they are being embedded and the statement that it could *probably* be done but with risk to damaging the board is entirely false.

Comment: The RAM chips themselves do not tell the controller how big or fast they are; that's the SPD's job. That functionality needs to be replaced, whether by a physical SPD chip, data on a different NVM or probing by the SMC for known configurations.

Comment: $200 is the extra cost of 16GB vs 8GB on a new computer, not the charge for Apple to perform the upgrade on an existing computer, which is what the OP wants to do.  You're not comparing (ahem) apples to apples.

Comment: "doing BGA rework doesn't damage the board": actually, yeah, it does. The parts and the PCBs are only rated for a small number of heat cycles - usually one. The PCB will delaminate after too many heat cycles. It's also very easy to desolder nearby parts or those on the backside of the board; see https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/Ik5Fl6oZmmIw1Brg.huge and https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/6vjM32B2PHbVd2AJ.huge. Not a huge issue here, but it's something you need to consider. Nobody gets a 100% success rate with this sort of work.

Comment: @NateEldredge  - I answered his question in the very first line of my answer

Comment: @IanHowson -  Moot point on SPD because it would be an added cost making it more cost prohibitory.  As far as BGA rework, I already noted that damage is mitigated to most of the board because it's focused heat.  Exactly how many times do you foresee BGA rework being done on a board to replace a chip?

Comment: @Allan: Question asks "is it possible", not "is it economical". SPD chips cost cents and reprogramming is free apart from labor, so I'm assuming that it is negligible compared with the RAM chips and rework labor. I'm not saying that damage is guaranteed, merely that it is possible. "Focused heat"? You're still going to heat the backside; if you can heat through the BGA package you will certainly heat through a multilayer PCB. As I said, the backside is not very dangerous in this case, but *it is not risk free*.

Answer (score 14):

You can definitely buy the requisite parts aftermarket - DigiKey would be the first place I would look. You could also remove the parts from another rMBP (e.g. flood damaged or something).

You can *probably* do the modification without damaging other things on the board, but it would be difficult. You are not going to do it at home. You're going to need someone very experienced with BGA rework with the appropriate equipment. It's a tightly packed double-sided board, so you need to be careful not to disturb other things nearby.

I don't know how the machine knows how much RAM it is supposed to have. It probably has an SPD chip, which you'd also need to replace or modify. It might be written to one of the many NVMs elsewhere on the board, which would be harder to modify. You can find schematics of the rMBP online, and they may tell you if there is an SPD chip.

The iFixit teardowns show that the lower-specced machines do not have empty space for more chips; Apple does RAM upgrades by putting higher density parts in the same locations.

So... it might be possible, but it won't be easy. I would recommend selling the old machine on eBay (resale price is good!) and buying a new one with the specs that you want.

Comment: Actually, if the module uses [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array), manually soldering them seems to be out of the question, due to the precision required and the inability to access the solder connection.

Comment: @Nelson Precision is fine; 0.8mm pitch is easily within the reach of a skilled operator. Nobody is suggesting that you can use a soldering iron to do this. Hot air rework is common for this sort of task.

Comment: This is a superior answer due to the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs. I don't know how we had a most-upvoted answer that didn't even bother to express scepticism or analysis of whether this upgrade could even be done.

Comment: A decent SM Tech could do it. Caveats, would be to have compatible frequencies, and matching pinouts between old and new chips. Don't listen to these guys that cant even solder tell you what can and cannot be done by soldering. Primary risk: your warranty is void. The motherboard could have a limitation on RAM. Can you run dmidecode on mac? that might be a brew install. you would need to read the SMBIOS tables to know the mobo limitation for Ram.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will be possible. The board will be manufactured with only that size of memory in mind, so the memory controller or other hardware would have to be changed too, and its not like there will be place for more memory chips.

One exception I can think of is if some higher model has more memory, then there might be some unpopulated place for chips.

See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53627/189360

Also reworking BGA packages is... very close to impossible. Sourcing bigger memory modules would be the easiest part as I doubt Apple would use the biggest ones available and sources like DigiKey have them.