# Extracting CPUs from multiple MacBook Pro's

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu

I have a couple old MacBook Pro's laying around and would like to put them to use. So here's the question.

Would it be possible to extract the CPUs from the boards, and connect them to a single logic board or some sort of adapter where they are both connected to the same machine?

I could you could think of it as a CPU rig.... and of course I'll be using it to mine cryptos :)

Comment: What research have you done to see if this is feasible.  This "adapter board" you reference...does it exist?

Comment: Also, CPUs are the wrong tool for the job.  You need a GPU.

Comment: @Allan Of course, but CPUs still get decent hash power

Comment: @Allan I was running under the assumption that the CPU could be disconnected from the board. Although I see now that it’s not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *believe* that Apple's portable lines use [surface mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology) technology, which means that the parts are mounted **directly** to the circuit board using specialized machinery common in the electronics industry.

There are few, if any, MacBooks made in the last decade that use socketed CPUs or GPUs. In fact, recently, Apple has taken to removing the sockets for RAM and storage (SSDs) meaning that you are stuck with the configuration as bought.

I have absolutely no doubt that someone with experience working with surface mounted parts could get the CPU/GPU off the PCBs. But then how are you going to mount the removed parts to another board?

You might be able to extract the system board from the case and then set it up to do as you would like, but removing parts from the PCB? Doubt it.

Comment: [It's entirely possible to remove/replace components from a PCB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243557/119271).  It's also quite easy to mount them to another part.  The question here (which makes it a poor one) is *what* board does the OP have in mind to attach said CPUs to.

Comment: I've known EEs who just threw up their hands at the thought of doing that. Good to know the technology has improved.

Comment: @Allan Yeah that was some poor wording. I’m just looking to aggregate the CPU power of multiple MacBook Pros. Since it appears that the parts are soldered onto the board, I guess the question now is could I aggregate the boards somehow?