# Single byte memtest errors — possible to tell which RAM chip is defective?

Tags: memory

I'm running memtest on a 2014 MacBook Air 11" with 8 GB memory spread over 4 Hynix chips.

I'm getting errors in the most significant byte of every (eighth) memory address when running memtest. After a while memtest just stops saying "too many errors occurred" (that's a nice line from an *error testing utility* ) so I don't know the extent of the error, nor do I see how I could find that out with a memory tool that repeatedly stops after ten minutes.

[image: memtest in progress]

Is it possible to narrow down which hardware component is probably faulty from this information?

Answer (score 1):

Not from that utility.  You’d need to see how the chips were laid out and what the addressing scheme was.  Since Apple doesn’t provide this, you’d be guessing.

Since these chips are soldered, they can’t be (user) replaced unless you take it to a shop that does [SMT rework](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243557/119271).

Keep in mind it could also be the memory “controller” that handles the addressing of the memory that’s has also failed.  Usually when this work is done, all chips are replaced.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be perfectly happy with someone other than Apple providing that information though. In the absence of it I guess I'd have to reseat all four chips, if possible.

Comment: Maybe it’s in board view?  Not sure, though

Comment: The board was subjected to some bending which is why I was hoping there'd just be a bad solder joint somewhere, but perhaps the bending was merely the result of frustration...